# Pass and return arrays value in Java

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

When the user clicks a button, I am trying to fill an array with x random numbers `(50,100,200...)` and return them back to pass them to other class , my query is

1)How to call the random class

2)How to return the filled array from the random class to the `onClick` method.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

 if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonone)
 {
 genrandom grandom =new genrandom();
 int[] arr=new int[50];
```

// this array will be used as a argument for other class

```
public class gen_random_number {

public void genrandom(int[] arr, int x) { 

Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  for (int idx = 1; idx <= x; ++idx){
       int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(5000);
                                    }       
     }  
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: u can try like this.

 public void onClick(View v) 

{ 
if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonone)
 {
 gen_random_number grandom =new gen_random_number(); 
int[] arr=gen_random_number.genrandom(); 


in your random generator class,

public class gen_random_number {

public int[] genrandom() { 

Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  int randonInt[] = new randomInt[50];
  for (int idx = 1; idx <= 100; ++idx){
     randomInt[idx] = randomGenerator.nextInt(5000);
                                    }       
     }  
     return randomInt;
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an **instance of gen_random_number** and call `getrandom()` passing your **array** and **x** as **parameters**.

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
     if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonone)
     {
       genrandom grandom =new genrandom();
       int[] arr=new int[50];
       arr = new  gen_random_number().genrandom(arr, yourXvalue);
   }
```

make the **return type** of **genrandom** an `int array`.

```
public int[] genrandom(int[] arr, int x) { 

Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  for (int idx = 1; idx <= x; ++idx){
       int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(5000);
          arr[idx] =randomInt;                        }       
     }  
     return arr;
  }
```

Comment: and what is the perpose of `int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(5000);`  line?

Comment: @imrankhan possibly to populate the array , i have updated the code :)

Comment: `arr = new  gen_random_number().genrandom(arr, yourXvalue);` passes the arr bits to genrandom in gen_random_number class